# Flutter application crashes on launch

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app I have been working on and it is published in the store already.   Has been running fine until some recent updates to flutter, the gradle, dart and android studio.   Have been working on this problem this whole week, trying to get it to run my apps again.   At the moment it seems to try and run the application which immediately closes on the phone.   There is no error as such but these are the latest lines from flutter run -v:

```
                 E: meta-data (line=181)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060001
[  +13 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM G970F.
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell am force-stop app.appname
[ +120 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell pm list packages app.appname
[ +222 ms] Installing APK.
[   +4 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +60 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.4-5871666
           Installed as C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +41 ms] Installing android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK install -t -r C:\Projects\Apps\app.appname\android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk
[+23392 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                     Success
[   +2 ms] Installing android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... (completed in 23.4s)
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell echo -n 0d4daf35397951507aa469d3eecceb6e826a3f62 > /data/local/tmp/sky.app.appname.sha1
[  +88 ms] SM G970F startApp
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez
enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true app.appname/app.appname.MainActivity
[ +125 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=app.appname/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

The application seems to crash the same instant the last line (waiting for observatory port) appears.  Not sure what I should be looking into here, or where it might be falling over.

EDIT:

Flutter doctor -v output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.10.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 1.10.7 at c:\flutter
    • Framework revision e70236e36c (2 weeks ago), 2019-10-02 09:32:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 9e6314d348
    • Dart version 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.4.0 1103600280)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\
    • Java binary at: C:\Installations\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Installations\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8580
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G970F • [xxxxx] • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Edit2:

[image: com.google.android.gms.version]

Comment: Can I see the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Absolutely you can, i'll add it to the question.   Also, I have just uninstalled android studio, flutter and dart from everywhere on my machine and set everything back up again from scratch.   Go to run the application and exactly the same error again :(

Comment: "com.google.android.gms.version" update this version in app gradle.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, Dhavel.   I have added a screenshot of my search for your suggestion in my app.  I do not have that line in any of my gradle files.   Is this a problem?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading your flutter to `stable` channel?

Comment: I suggest that you run on the Android Studio and see the logs from Logcat ... In my case I was having a trivial issue that the `MainActivity` & `MainApplication` had the wrong package name compared to the `AndroidMainifest.xml`, Solving that my issue has been resolved